# How to use 'adaboost' distribution in 'gbm' to have a meaningful prediction?

Tags: r, gbm, adaboost

So, here is what is going on - I have the Titanic dataset with the following 9 columns:

> (i) Survived (0/1) [2 levels],
>
> (ii) Pclass(1/2/3) [3 levels],
>
> (iii) Sex(M/F) [2 levels],
>
> (iv) Age (continuous variable),
>
> (v) Fare (continuous variable),
>
> (vi) Embarked(C/Q/S) [3 levels],
>
> (vii) SibSp (continuous variable),
>
> (viii) Parch (continuous variable), and
>
> (ix) Titles (Mr/MsMrs/Master/X) [4 levels].

I am trying to predict `Survived` from the other eight using the `gbm` package in `R` and I use the following:

```
fit.gbm = gbm(Survived ~ Age + Fare + SibSp + Parch + Pclass + Titles + Sex + Embarked , data=train , distribution = "adaboost", n.trees=500 , interaction.depth=3 , shrinkage=0.005)
```

Then I use

```
predd.gbm = predict(fit.gbm , newdata=train , type="response" , n.trees=500)
```

And I don't understand what I am getting because everything in predd.gbm looks like 0.99983 , 0.999974, etc. How do I make sense of what I am getting and how do I predict 0/1 from this weird predd.gbm-"probability" where every element is close to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Aaah, so the way to do it is change (i) from factor to numeric using:

```
train$Survived = as.numeric(train$Survived)
```

`randomForest` understands that Survived is a factor but `gbm` doesn't!